# How to properly use Atuhentication and User Creation forms in django?

Tags: django

I'm looking for less-code-way of implementation of registration and authorization. How to implement it without using self-written views and forms. I want to use something like this:

```
url(r'^login/', django.contrib.auth.views.login, {"template_name": "auth/login.html"}, name='Login'),
url(r'^register/', if.this.builtin.view.exists.register, {"template_name": "auth/register.html"},  name='Register'),
```

login/register.html:

```
{% block content %} {% crispy form %} {% endblock %}
```

Is there similar ways?

Comment: look here how I did it: http://www.django-tips.com/tip/reuse-djangos-register-form-if-you-dont-have-your-own-huge-number-of-register-fields/22/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no views for django registration, but there is UserCreationForm in `django.contrib.auth.forms`. View must be written by developer. And it is logically. Realize it!